# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied VS2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am getting following error while running my asp.net web application through VS2013.

**Error**:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0c9c5fe5\51acd19b' is denied.

FYI, I was getting some error earlier and to resolve that error I deleted all files inside "Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\" folder which caused above error.

I tried following:
- Restarted VS2013 using admin privilege!
- Added full permissions IIS_IUSRS on my web app folder - C:\Samples\ASP.NET\WebApp1
- Added full permissions IIS_IUSRS on my aspnet temp folder - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root

Please help!

[image]

Comment: You probably shouldn't delete that folder... It's explained at [Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). Can you create a new project and copy all your files to that project perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are any of the dlls in your solution  marked as readonly?

Have they been checked out from source control?

Did you reboot after changing the permissions?

What is the identity of the Application Pool User, do they have access to the temp folder?

Is your web app impersonating another user at all?

Is your App doing anything on bootup, that could cause this?

Use SysInternals [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) to see if another process is using it.

Comment: Thanks @ralph-willgoss, None of the assemblies are marked readonly. I rebooted the system and the error is gone. However, I got my original error back: Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'NorthwindApp.DAL.Categories' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0c9c5fe5\51acd19b\assembly\dl3\ab057b39\a0a21d7d_b826d001\NorthwindApp.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0c9c5fe5\51acd19b\App_Code.ryyqawx5.dll'

Comment: Thanks again @ralph-willgoss, please create an answer and will mark as resolved for now.

Comment: One of the important fact, why I was struggling with the kind of errors, was because I was using "App_Code" folder in my Web Application Project". Please note that "App_Code" folder can only be used in Website projects, not Web App projects!!!

So, if you want to put some class files and compile them, you will need to create a folder other than "App_code", even "AppCode" without underscore character should work...

Very good article by Vishal [App_Code folder doesn’t work with Web Application Projects (WAPs)](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html)

Answer (score 16):

For me the problem was caused by the Exception Settings.
Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings
In the window that is shown uncheck -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions

I turn it on from time to time to break on all errors including handled ones and had left it on. Then when debugging my ASP.Net MVC app it then halts on the access denied errors on start. My guess is it tries to write temp files to Location A, gets an access denied error, then uses Location B.

Comment: Exact same scenario. The thought never crossed my mind that fiddling with my exception settings affected core functioning Microsoft code this way

Comment: @bkwdesign It only does if you have "Just My Code" disabled. Normally VS is supposed to see that the exception wasn't in your code, and so the first-chance exception handling logic isn't applied, whether you have it enabled or not.

Comment: If you also have just my code disabled, and you want it that way, you can stop this error from occurring by running VS as administrator.

Comment: My issue was that exceptions weren't being caught by MSVC (found this whilst trying to understand why). Turning on exceptions caught the exceptions but it was quite worrying when this exception (and others) were caught. Selecting "Just My Code" (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx) seemed to filter the exceptions to show issues in my code only and not with the .NET framework.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by adding read write permissions for "IUSR" to the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder. The IIS_IUSRS didnt seem to work for some odd reason.

Comment: Worked for me: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017