# No relevant source lines - Source file could not be opened ('Unspecified error ')

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.8

I am running a 32-bit ASP.NET application using .NET Framework 4.8. I am getting the following error when starting the application:

```
error CS1504: Source file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\...\xxx.cs' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ')
```

**What I have tried**

- Running the application in IISExpress and Local IIS both in 32-bit mode.
- Updating Visual Studio
- Rebooting
- Reinstalling Visual Studio 2022 and .NET Framework 4.8
- Move the location of the temporary files folder to a different location using configuration
- Remove the Temp folder/files / clean / rebuild

Comment: There are several answers on this similar post that may help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745742/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-denied-vs2013/36301485#36301485

Comment: does it actually say `xxx.cs`? Or you are for some reason uncomfortable specifying the name of Microsoft file?

Comment: Hi @Felix, the directory ends in `18094c30\2bb837cd\App_global.asax.613u7ful.0.cs`. There is not much meaning there.

Comment: yes there is. It is the file that gets generated from your code (from `App_global.asax` - I am writing from memory here, it has been more than 5 years since I touched .Net Framework); rather than Microsoft file. I assume that you checked and the file is indeed missing. Are you sure that your project got built successfully?

Comment: The file is in fact present in that directory. I do get a couple of `Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpCompileException' in System.Web.dll` these errors in the output window of the debug tab. However, there are no build errors when I perform a build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the issue was. There were language features that needed to be installed through Visual Studio 2022.

Go to Build => ASP.NET Compilation => Enable latest C# and VB language features

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try -
Delete the 'Temporary ASP.NET Files' folder. Restart your computer, clean the solution and rebuild the solution

Comment: That is not working mate.